# Issues adding my own custom CA in Firefox after updating to newer version

Tags: linux, firefox, ca, certutil

I had Firefox 52.7.0 on my Linux host which is running fine.
Also, I have my own CA certificate which I add using `certutil` command:

`$ certutil -d ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiledir -A -n myca -i ./myca.pem -t CT,,`

I can see `myca` it's being added by issuing this command:

`$ certutil -d ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiledir -L`

When I navigate to `Preferences` - `Advanced` - `Certificates` - `View Certificates` I can see my certificate in the list.

At some point I decided I don't have enough excitement in my life, so I decided to upgrade Firefox to a newer version. The version I downloaded is Firefox 102.1.0esr for Linux.
However, `certutil` adds my CA certificate (I see it using `certutil -L`), but when I navigate to `Settings` - `Privacy & Security` - `Certificates` - `View Certificates` I don't see my newly added CA  in the list. Of course, the certificate is not being used by Firefox because of this.

I would assume the way to add a custom CA certificate changed between Firefox 52 and 102. What's the current way of adding my own CA to Firefox?
[Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/AddRootToFirefox) shows `certutil` is still one way of adding it. Maybe the way I add it is no longer valid with the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears starting with Firefox 58 the file used for user certificates changed from `cert8.db` to `cert9.db`.
In order for `certutil` to use `cert9.db`, I had to prepend "sql:" for `-d` option.

The final command would look like:

`certutil -d sql:~/.mozilla/firefox/profiledir -A -n myca -i ./myca.pem -t CT,,`